# Can I "need" something that is not essential?

Tags: meaning

I think that a "need" can indicate that whatever is needed is essential:

- I need to be the best.

But can I "need" something that is not essential? e.g., even-though locking the door is all I have to do to stop the zombies

- I need to lock the door and find my gun, to stop the zombies.

Locking the door is essential, and finding my gun is not. Do I need my gun?

Comment: Needing can partake in emotions; emotions being volatile as they are cannot guarantee basic necessity for they can arise from unnatural states of mental affection and distress; yet, a need surges in the form impulse. Is it justifiable as something obligatory? not necessarily. Do we need a drink when under stress? Maybe yes. I don't think the important aspect here is the end but the need-generating impulse.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"need" can also be used for something non-essential for survival:

"a physiological or psychological requirement for the well-being of an organism"

"He has trouble expressing his emotional needs."

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/need

Comment: maybe not a very good question for this site, tho clarifying it to post did help. thanks

Comment: You're very welcome, my friend.

Comment: It's a fair question; you should tag it under etymology aswell to seek meaning in the very root of the word. Old English neodian "be necessary, be required (for some purpose); require, have need of," from the same root as need (n.). Meaning "to be under obligation (to do something)" is from late 14c. Related: Needed; needing. The adjectival phrase need-to-know is attested from 1952. Dismissive phrase who needs it?, popular from c. 1960, is a translated Yiddishism. If you're looking for a deeper meaning for need in contrast to desire, that would be more of a philosophical question rather.

Comment: @Parmenides Ephesus If your comment was addressed to me, I don't know how to tag.

Comment: Done it for you.

Comment: Is your question regarding the difference of needing something out of natural necessity in contrast to those needs that no matter if surfeited still generate a need? or also about the needs arisen from a desire that does not respect basic necessity?